# JEE6 version of ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()

Tags: java-ee-6

Aside from storing it in the context or hard coding it somewhere is there any standard equivalent to [ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getVirtualServerName--)

The purpose of which is for developing a JASPIC AuthConfigProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, `ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()` was specifically meant to fill that exact gap in the specs.

Comment: I was hoping someone else can provide a more hopeful answer but ya I had a feeling this was the case.